# Adding appcompat-v7 makes an error in gen

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

Whenever I import the `appcompat_v7 library` (and yes I have tried multiple versions ex: the generated, from GitHub, from /extras) it gives me an error in my project in the `Gen files`. 
It removes one closing bracket from the generated `R.java` file and I cannot fix this unless I un-import the library. On my most recent attempt it even made it so I couldn't use other imports, such as me QR Scanning library.

I could just remove it altogether and not use it, but it would help with CardViews and RecyclerViews.

Comment: Delete the `gen` folder and `build project` again.

Comment: Check your android eclipse plugin,or just use studio.The eclipse plugin is very temperamental